# How do I independently change the width and height of a font in .NET?

Tags: .net, fonts

Given something like this:

`thefont = New Font("Courier New", fontheight)`

and this:

`' g is a Graphics object`

`g.DrawString("some text", thefont, Brushes.Black, X, Y)`

what can I put in the middle of the two to change the width of the font, so that "some text" is expanded or compressed horizontally but the height remains the same?

Answer (score 4):

You could do it using a scale transform, like this:

```
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.Scale(3, 1);
        g.Transform = m;
        g.DrawString("Some text", this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10, 10));
        g.ResetTransform();
```